# Two Columns Table in elsarticle Document Class

Tags: tables, longtable, two-column, elsarticle, supertabular

I'm trying to create a pretty long table in an `elsarticle.cls` with a two column layout. However, I haven't been able to find a suitable option to break my table so it can fit on a single page and using the two column setting. I provide this example:

```
\documentclass[5p]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\newcommand{\Title}[1]{\justifying\caption{#1}}
\newcommand{\Source}[1]{\caption*{\justifying\textbf{Source:} #1}}
\newcommand{\Note}[1]{\caption*{\justifying\textbf{Note:} #1}}

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------
\begin{frontmatter}

   \title{Two column tables in elsarticle document class}

   \author{A. J. Lee}

   \begin{abstract}
      This document asks how to break tables in two column documents.
   \end{abstract}

\end{frontmatter}

%----------------------------------
\section{Introduction}
   See table  
\begin{table}[H]
   \centering
   \begin{tabular}{p{1cm} p{1cm} p{5cm}}
   % Header
   \toprule
   \textbf{Item} & 
   \textbf{Code} & 
   % Content
   \textbf{Description} \\
   \midrule
   % Content
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}
   \Title{Table}
   \Source{Own creation}
   \Note{This is an example}
\end{table}
```

Since this is a two column layout I can't use the `longtable` package. Also, I haven't used the `supertabular` package since I have created some new commands: `\Title`, `\Source` and `\Note`, and there is no place (I guess) for them within the `supertabular` options and maitaining the same appearance.

This is my pdf outcome:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure about your self-defined commands `\Source` and `\Note`?. To me, using the `caption` command for them does not seem to be a good idea, as this will most likely lead to strange numbering of the tables.

Comment: It is possible to put a longtable into two columns (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316767/how-to-float-long-table-to-next-page-without-influence-the-two-column-layout/316856?s=12|14.1157#316856) but only if it takes up the entire column.

Comment: @leandriis yes, they work properly. Since I use `\caption*` instead of `\caption` there's no numbering conflict.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I don't think using images would be a good idea since they may suffer some downgrades.

Comment: PDFs are not pixelated, and suffer no loss of resolution when copied.  Even inserted pixelated images are stored in their original resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve a similar result using the `supertabular` package:

```
\documentclass[5p]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{supertabular}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

   \title{Two column tables in elsarticle document class}

   \author{A. J. Lee}

   \begin{abstract}
      This document asks how to break tables in two column documents.
   \end{abstract}

\end{frontmatter}

\section{Introduction}
   See table

\begin{center}
\tablehead{%
   \toprule
   \textbf{Item} & 
   \textbf{Code} & 
   \textbf{Description} \\
   \midrule}
\bottomcaption{Table caption}
\begin{supertabular}{p{1cm} p{1cm} p{5cm}}
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   \bottomrule
\end{supertabular}
\justifying
\textbf{Source:} Here is the source of the table

\textbf{Notes:} Here are some table notes
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @leandriss Thank you for your help. I solved the problem. I think I was missing something when using the `supertabular` package. Any way, I used a little hack to solve the captions problem. I will provide the code bellow.

Answer (score 0):

This solution to my problem is based on @leandriss' own solution. I just (1) added some options to my captions so they look better, (2) used more of the `supertabular` package options, and (3) used an empty `table` environment with the `[H]` option from the `float` package at the end of the table and some `\vspace` adjustment. I share the code:

```
\documentclass[authoryear,5p]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage[skip = 2pt,
           font = footnotesize,
           label font = bf,
           justification = justified]{caption} % Etiquetas
\captionsetup{justification = justified,
             singlelinecheck = false} % Alinear etiquetas a la izquierda.

\newcommand{\Title}[1]{\caption{#1}}
\newcommand{\Source}[1]{\caption*{\justifying\textbf{Fuente:} #1}}
\newcommand{\Note}[1]{\caption*{\justifying\textbf{Nota:} #1}}

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------
\begin{frontmatter}

   \title{Two column tables in elsarticle document class}

   \author{A. J. Lee}

   \begin{abstract}
      This document asks how to break table in two column documents.
   \end{abstract}

\end{frontmatter}

%----------------------------------
\section{Introduction}
   See table:  \ref{tab:1}.
\begin{center}
   % Main Header
   \tablefirsthead{%
      \toprule
      \textbf{Item} & 
      \textbf{Code} & 
      \textbf{Description} \\
   \midrule
   }
   % Tail
   \tabletail{%
      \midrule
      \multicolumn{3}{l}{\emph{cotinue}} \\
      \midrule
   }
   % Head
   \tablehead{%
      \midrule
      \multicolumn{3}{l}{\emph{cotinue}} \\
      \midrule
   }
   % Last Tail
   \tablelasttail{%
      \bottomrule
   }
   \begin{supertabular}{p{1cm} p{1cm} p{5cm}}
   % Content
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   A & 777 & Some random stuff \\
   \end{supertabular}
\end{center} \vspace{-16pt}
\begin{table}[H]
   \Title{Table}
   \label{tab:1}
   \Source{Own creation}
   \Note{This is an example}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This is the final outcome:

[image]