# wrap text beside longtable

Tags: tables, positioning, longtable, wrap, overleaf

i have a question about longtables. Is it possible to get a text wrapped around a (right-situated) longtable? I am using the longtable package and this is my code:

```
  \begin{longtable}[r]{| r | r | r |}
 \caption{some caption)\\

\hline
 \multicolumn{3}{| r |}{Heading}\\
 \hline
 \large bla & bla & bla \\
 \hline
  \endfirsthead
   \hline
 \endhead

 \hline
 \endfoot
 \hline


 \multicolumn{3}{| r |}{Reference
 \footnotesize{*Estimation}}\\
 \hline\hline
 \endlastfoot

Incidence   & &\\
1958-1962: & number  & number  \\
2013-2017 & number & number \\
\cline{1-3}
Text  & &\\
1978-1982 & number & number \\
2013-2017& number & number* \\

 \end{longtable}
 \label{table:somename}
```

I would greatly appreciate if someone can help me.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316767/how-to-float-long-table-to-next-page-without-influence-the-two-column-layout/316856?r=SearchResults&s=16|14.2211#316856

Comment: Thank you for your response, but i dont understand how the answers to the questions asked here can help me?

Comment: I am assuming you intend to extend this for several pages.  Otherwise, don't use longtable.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step, determine the height and width needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\sbox0{\begin{tabular}{| r | r | r |}
 \multicolumn{3}{| r |}{Reference
 \footnotesize{*Estimation}}\\
 \hline\hline
Incidence   & &\\
1958-1962: & number  & number  \\
2013-2017 & number & number \\
\cline{1-3}
Text  & &\\
1978-1982 & number & number \\
2013-2017& number & number* \\
\end{tabular}}

height=\the\textheight

width=\the\wd0
\end{document}
```

---

Next step, store the longtable in a separate document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0pt,paperheight=550pt,paperwidth=153.2781pt,noheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
%\setcounter{table}{2}
\begin{longtable}{| r | r | r |}
 \caption{some caption}\\
\hline
 \multicolumn{3}{| r |}{Heading}\\
 \hline
 \large bla & bla & bla \\
 \hline
  \endfirsthead
   \hline
 \endhead
 \hline
 \endfoot
 \hline
 \multicolumn{3}{| r |}{Reference
 \footnotesize{*Estimation}}\\
 \hline\hline
 \endlastfoot
Incidence   & &\\
1958-1962: & number  & number  \\
2013-2017 & number & number \\
\cline{1-3}
Text  & &\\
1978-1982 & number & number \\
2013-2017& number & number* \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

---

Step 3, insert the pages into your document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0pt}
  \refstepcounter{table}\label{table:somename}%
  \includegraphics[page=1]{test5}% document stored as test5.pdf
\end{wrapfigure}
\sloppy
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\globalcounter{table}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\setcolumnwidth{\dimexpr \textwidth-\columnsep-153.2781pt\relax,153.2781pt}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\sloppy
\lipsum[1-2]
\switchcolumn
\refstepcounter{table}\label{table:somename}%
\includegraphics[page=1]{test5}% document stored as test5.pdf
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

There is no good way to start and stop the text wrap, unless they happen at paragraph boundaries.  You can break a paragraph at the top of a page by inserting wrapfigure at precisely the right spot.  Each image should be 550pt high, even the last page.  You can end the wrap early using \WFclear, but only between paragraphs.

You will also need to manually insert an entry into the list of tables, or possibly use the xr package to copy the entry from `test5.aux`.