# Wrapping an entire longtable on the same page

Tags: tables, longtable, multicol

I'm trying to wrap an entire table that's 2 columns wide but longer than a page. Here is my code and what it looks like:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|}
    \caption{Dimmer to Channel Relationships}
    \label{table:channels}

    \hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Channel}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Dimmer}} \\ \hline
    \endfirsthead

    \multicolumn{2}{c}{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued}} \\

    \hline \textbf{Channel} & \textbf{Dimmer} \\ \hline
    \endhead

    \hline \multicolumn{2}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
    \endfoot

    \hline
    \endlastfoot

    1 $\rightarrow$ 17 & 1 $\rightarrow$ 17 \\
    % Other values here
    48 $\rightarrow$ 48 & 48 $\rightarrow$ 27 \\
    ... $\rightarrow$ ... & ... $\rightarrow$ ... \\
    2000 $\rightarrow$ 2000 & 2000 $\rightarrow$ 2000 \\
    2001 $\rightarrow$ nil & 2001 $\rightarrow$ nil \\
    ... $\rightarrow$ nil & ... $\rightarrow$ nil \\
    2048 $\rightarrow$ nil & 2048 $\rightarrow$ nil
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
```

Starting page:
[image: Image 1]
Wrapped page:
[image: Image 2]

What I am trying to do is achieve this (where the red arrow indicates that the values continue there and not to the next page):

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Longtable will not work with twocolumn and is too closely tied to \output to use a savebox.  Best advice is to look for a longtable alternate which can handle columns or create the longtable in another document and copy it.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469547/wrap-text-beside-longtable