# Longtable and wrapping text around it

Tags: longtable, wrap

How could I arrange a longtable, which spans through multiple pages, to be also wrapped by text around it?
The longtable looses the benefits if put inside the wraptable environment.

Comment: long table are necessarily full width to allow page breaking

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469547/wrap-text-beside-longtable

Comment: Thanks John for pointing me to that link.