# How to scalebox a longtable?

Tags: longtable, scaling

Good afternoon !

I have a longtable split in 4 pages within a pdf called results.tex. I need to include that pdf in another main.tex file ( This main.tex file uses some journal template format ) :

**results.tex :**

```
\documentclass[times]{iapress}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[longtable]{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage[left=0.1in,right=0.1in,top=0.0in,bottom=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[left=0.2in,right=0.2in,top=0.0in,bottom=0.0in]{geometry}

\usepackage{moreverb}
\usepackage[dvips,colorlinks,bookmarksopen,bookmarksnumbered,citecolor=red,urlcolor=red]{hyperref}

%%
 
 

%%
\def\volumeyear{202x}
\def\volumenumber{x}
\def\volumemonth{Month}
\setcounter{page}{00}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.01}
%%

\usepackage{tikz}


\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\newcommand{\Lpagenumber}{\ifdim\textwidth=\linewidth\else\bgroup
  \dimendef\margin=0 %use \margin instead of \dimen0
  \ifodd\value{page}\margin=\oddsidemargin
  \else\margin=\evensidemargin
  \fi
  \raisebox{\dimexpr -\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep-0.5\linewidth}[0pt][0pt]{%
    \rlap{\hspace{\dimexpr \margin+\textheight+\footskip}%
    \llap{\rotatebox{90}{\thepage}}}}%
\egroup\fi}
%%\AddEverypageHook{\Lpagenumber}%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.9}

\lstset{
basicstyle=\scriptsize\tt,
}
%%
\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2
}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}





\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

 

\begin{landscape}
 
 \renewcommand\thetable{11} 
 

\begin{longtable}{|c|c|l|l|l|cl|} 


\caption{Some simulation results of the suggested hybrid optimizer}
\\
\hline
Test function 
  & Study domain 
    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} 
                          initial obtained solution (Algorithm 2 )
                          \end{tabular}} 
      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} 
                            Obtained hybrid\\ 
                            optimizer solution\\ 
                            (Algorithm 3 ) 
                            \end{tabular}} 
        & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} 
                             Objective\\ 
                             function\\ 
                             value  of the\\  
                             solution 
                             \end{tabular}} 
          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\* 
\hline
\multirow{13}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}   Sphere \\    ( dim = 13 )   \end{tabular}} 
  & \multirow{13}{*}{$ [-6,6]^{13} $ } 
    & $ Nbre\_iter=5  \;\; N=20 \; \; P=4 $  
      & \multirow{13}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} 
                        $X1=-0.553850768$ \\ 
                        $X2=-1.493074761$\\ 
                        $X3=0.6767506500$ \\ 
                        $X4=-0.602909613$ \\ 
                        $X5=-1.047292736$ \\ 
                        $X6=-0.191411525$ \\ 
                        $X7=-0.079137285$ \\ 
                        $X8=0.2588126665$ \\ 
                        $X9=-1.444664397$ \\ 
                        $X10=-0.92061842$ \\ 
                        $X11=0.424461785$ \\ 
                        $X12=-0.38351937$ \\ 
                        $X13=-0.15875219$ \end{tabular} } 
        & \multirow{13}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} 
                          $X1=-4.9999e-09$ \\ 
                          $X2=-5.0000e-09$ \\ 
                          $X3=-5e-09$ \\ 
                          $X4=-5e-09$ \\ 
                          $X5=-5e-09$ \\ 
                          $X6=-5e-09$ \\ 
                          $X7=-5.000003e-09$ \\ 
                          $X8=-4.307553e-09$ \\ 
                          $X9=-5.0000006e-09$ \\ 
                          $X10=-5e-09$ \\ 
                          $X11=-5.000723e-09$ \\ 
                          $X12=-5.392374e-09$ \\ 
                          $X13=-5.00000000053859e-09$ \end{tabular}} 
          & \multirow{13}{*}{$ 3.22640e-16  $ } &  \\* 
\cline{3-3}
 &  
   & \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}} 
     $ \text{Iter} =50 $\\
     $\alpha=0.1$\\
     $\gamma=0.99$    
     \end{tabular} 
     &  &  &  &  \\ 
     &&&&&& \\
     &&&&&& \\ 
     &&&&&& \\ 
     &&&&&& \\
     &&&&&& \\
     &&&&&& \\
     &&&&&& \\
     &&&&&& \\
     &&&&&& \\


     \hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

**main.tex :**

```
%%\documentclass[notitlepage]{article}
\documentclass[times]{iapress}
\usepackage{moreverb}
\usepackage[dvips,colorlinks,bookmarksopen,bookmarksnumbered,citecolor=red,urlcolor=red]{hyperref}

%%
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

%%
\def\volumeyear{202x}
\def\volumenumber{x}
\def\volumemonth{Month}
\setcounter{page}{00}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.01}
%%

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}

\usepackage{longtable}

%\usepackage{algorithm}

\usepackage{algorithmic}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[ ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{authblk} 
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%% attention here ! 
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.9}

\lstset{
basicstyle=\scriptsize\tt,
}
%%
\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2
}
\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages={1-4}, pagecommand={}]{../figures/result.pdf}

\end{document}
```

When I compile the main.tex file , I get the table sticked to the left  :

[image]

The used iapress class files could be found here :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M3ZEjdt6PSXOuzN9d2Ex4CYdOjtBAGNI/view?usp=sharing

Thank you a lot for your help !

Comment: Instead of trying to rescale the table, which will lead to inconsistent and most likely illegibly small font sizes, I suggest redesigning the table in order to make sure it fits into the available space. You could, for example, save a lot of space by allowing linebreaks in some of the cells or by adjusting the column widths.

Comment: Why did you decide to produce the table separately and later on include the resulting pdf file into your main tex file? Both files seem to share the same (or at least a very similar)  preamble, so why the two separate files?

Comment: @leandriis , i need only a way to adjust the table to the left / right

Comment: For me the pb is near being solved !

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316767/how-to-float-long-table-to-next-page-without-influence-the-two-column-layout/316856?r=SearchResults&s=2|19.9807#316856

Comment: never apply scaling to tables it does not give an error with `tabular` but gives horrible results, and does not work at all with `longtable`. For your comment about moving the table left or right `longtable`  provide `\LTleft` and `\LTright` to adjust the spacing. To make teh text smaller do not use scalebox use `\small` or `\footnotesize` to choose an appropriate font size.