# longtblr in multicols environment

Tags: tabularray

I have a document with a very long (the data are coming from an external file) but narrow table in it, and I would like to split it in a multicols environment, instead of having this table spread over several pages.
Unfortunetely, this does not work, I have the three columns of the page, but the table is only in the first one, and goes beyond the end of the page.

Has anyone any ideas?

Has anyone any idea how to do it?

```
\documentclass[
  10pt,
  paper=a4,
  twoside=true,
  openany,
  ]{scrbook}
\usepackage{multicol}           % Intermix single and multiple columns.
\usepackage{tabularray}         % Typeset tabulars and arrays with LATEX3

\UseTblrLibrary{diagbox, functional, siunitx, varwidth}

\begin{document}
  \begin{multicols}{3}
    \begin{longtblr}[evaluate=\fileInput]
    {
      colspec = S|[dashed]S,
      width = 0.20\linewidth,
      measure = vbox,
      rowhead = 1,
      rowfoot = 0,
      row{1} = {halign=center, font=\bfseries},
    }
     $^\circ$C & $\Omega$    \\ \hline
        -40 & 107,627   \\
        -39 & 100,100   \\
        -38 & 93,170    \\
        -37 & 86,787    \\
        -36 & 80,903    \\
        -35 & 75,476    \\
        -34 & 70,465    \\
        -33 & 65,835    \\
        -32 & 61,551    \\
        -31 & 57,586    \\
      \fileInput{TableValues.tmp}
    \end{longtblr}
  \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). We do not have `TableValues.tmp`. And `\begin{document}` should be before `\begin{multicols}{3}`.

Comment: Yeap,
sorry about that, I inverted while copying from my source file (I cut half the document).
Added also some lines of the table

Comment: Longtable (and presumably longtblr) interact with \output to handle the page breaking.  Multicols puts an entire page into one \savebox then splits it.  You could create a document with very narrow pages and copy the PDF using \includegraphics.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316767/how-to-float-long-table-to-next-page-without-influence-the-two-column-layout/316856?r=SearchResults&s=4%7C18.3771#316856

Comment: It would probably be easier just to create 2 or more separate tabulars.

Comment: I though about creating seperate tabulars, but in that case I would have to split manually the table, which is not very easy, since I do not know where that table start on the page height (it is in the middle of a section).
Idem if going via the external pdf file, this implies that the heigh of the table on the first page is identical to the one of all the remaining pages.